# Echo implemented in Java

Tags: java, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, console, unix

I implemented a simple version of [echo(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=echo&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) command utility. The program works as described in the man page: it writes to the standard output all command line arguments, separated by a whitespace and end with a newline. It can process the option `-n` that avoid to print the newline.

About my implementation, it is not complete, because it doesn't interpret common backslash-escaped characters (for example `\n`, `\c`, and so forth). i used a `StringBuilder` object to build the output string, because I'm not sure that the standard output is buffered. I also make some checks so the program can work without specifying any arguments.

You can compile the program with `javac JEcho` and run it with `java JEcho <...>`.

**JEcho.java**

```
/**
 * JEcho writes any command line argument to the standard output; each argument
 * is separated by a single whitespace and end with a newline (you can
 * specify '-n' to suppress the newline).
 *
 * This program doesn't interpret common backslash-escaped characters (for
 * exampe '\n' or '\c').
 */
public class JEcho {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean printNewline = true;
        int posArgs = 0;

        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-n")) {
                printNewline = false;
                posArgs = 1;
        }

        StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (; posArgs < args.length; posArgs++) {
            outputBuilder.append(args[posArgs]);
            outputBuilder.append(" "); // Separator.
        }

        // Remove the trailing whitespace at the end.
        int outputLength = outputBuilder.length();
        if (outputLength > 0)
            outputBuilder.deleteCharAt(outputBuilder.length() - 1);

        String output = outputBuilder.toString();

        if (printNewline)
            System.out.println(output);
        else
            System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the purpose of JEcho? is it akademical or du you want to proof something? do you want to write n utility for your home computer?

Comment: why don't you print the arguments directly?

Comment: @MartinFrank I'm learning Java, so I'm reimplementing some utilities that I use frequently. This program is not production ready, it is only an exercise.

Comment: @MartinFrank because I need to separate all arguments with a whitespace and because I don't know if the standard output is buffered.

Comment: A standard POSIX echo doesn't interpolate any backslash escapes either, so this is a faithful implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can use [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

```
/**
 * JEcho writes any command line argument to the standard output; each argument
 * is separated by a single whitespace and end with a newline (you can
 * specify '-n' to suppress the newline).
 *
 * This program doesn't interpret common backslash-escaped characters (for
 * exampe '\n' or '\c').
 */
public class JEcho {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean printNewline = true;
        int posArgs = 0;

        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-n")) {
                printNewline = false;
                posArgs = 1;
        }

        StringJoiner outputBuilder = new StringJoiner(" ");

        for (; posArgs < args.length; posArgs++) {
            outputBuilder.add(args[posArgs]);
        }

        String output = outputBuilder.toString();

        if (printNewline)
            System.out.println(output);
        else
            System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the differences between `StringBuilder` and `StringJoiner`?

Comment: @ema-pe I accidentally forgot the " " argument. `StringJoiner` adds something between the values.

Comment: Doesn't Java have a `foreach`, or doesn't have something similar to C# `String.Join( separator, value )` where `separator` would be the `" "` and `value` the `args`?

**EDIT**: I've seen that Java as a similar method, so why don't use it?

Comment: @auhmaan, the `-n` argument complicates things.

Answer (score 2):

as a matter of an excersice i would advise you to keep your parameters as `List<String>`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean printNewline = true;
    List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(args);
    if (args.length > 0 && isNewLine(args[0]) ) {
        printNewline = false;
        parameters.remove(0); //remove the first one
    }

    String output = parameters.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "", printNewLine ? System.lineSeparator() : "")

    System.out.print(output);
}
```

NOTE: the method `isNewLine()` is not shown here - but you should consider using such a method to prevent a missing argument... think of `-n`, `-N`, `/n`, `/N`, all these parameters can be handle in the `isNewLine`-method...

Comment: I would push the ternary op as deep as possible: `parameters.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(printNewLine ?"\n":","))`

Comment: man - formatting in stackjoverflow always tears me down =) haha

Comment: very nice @Landei - would you please edit my post!

Comment: thank you for doing so @Landei - it looks far more better now!!

Comment: This doesn't do the same as the question. Namely, `printNewLine` should print a line *after* the rest of the string, not as word separator. Then, the separator is always a whitespace, not `","`. Fixing these is rather easy actually: `Collectors.joining(" ", "", printNewLine ? System.lineSeparator() : "")` and using `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`.

Comment: i have added your valuable input @OlivierGrégoire thank you so much for precising this requirement! - even though you tried to edit my post it was disapproved... very bad, considering the comments where i especially asked you to do so - anyway, keep up the good work & thanks again!